# Multiplicity of a 2 state gas

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, statistics, gas

Consider a gas with $N$ non-interacting particles and each particle can have energy $E_0=\epsilon_0$ or $E_1=\epsilon_1$.

The total energy is therefore

$U=n_0\epsilon_0 + n_1\epsilon_1$

where $n_0$ and $n_1$ are the numbers of particles in states $0$ and $1$, respectively.

Since there are only 2 energy levels, the number of unique microstates is $2^N$, correct?

Would you call this the "multiplicity"?

My main question is: Is there a way to calculate the multiplicity for the number of possible macrostates?

Comment: There are more microstates than that. If the particle could only have the energy $E_0$ for example, each particle could have a given position in space. There would exist as much microstates as much position possible for all your particles (assuming the position don't change the energy of those).

Comment: @StarBucK, I see. I changed my question to make this a gas of *noninteracting* particles, so the positions do not change the energy.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that your $2^N$ represent the number of way to attribute an energy value to your particles. But this isn't the number of microstates. Imagine you have $2$ particles, their energies can be $(E_0, E_0)$, $(E_0, E_1)$, $(E_1, E_0)$, $(E_1, E_1)$. But your number of microstates is way bigger than this. because for each choice possible your particles have a lot of position possible in your  box for example.

Comment: @StarBucK Yeah makes sense... Well I'm at loss how to find the number of microstates then. I don't have the total number of available spaces/positions.

Comment: @Drew, apparently you consider  the particles are *distinguishable*, this is an important point since the answer depends on it.

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist, but I'm pretty sure particles in this example are *indistinguishable* since exchanging particles does not affect the total energy. I simply want to find the multiplicity of indistinguishable particles that are allowed 2 energy states.

Comment: @Drew, but then the number of unique microstates is **not** $2^N$

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist, I see, I understand that now. But what should the number of unique microstates be then? Surely we cant care about positions of gas particles, so I dont think that should matter right?

Comment: @Drew, yes changing position do not change energy state. so you can think  your particles sitting in two(distinguishable) cells. As to the number of unique microstates, the answer is $N+1$, I'm sure you'll find the combinatorics behind this.